# what's wrong with this "please wait" implementation?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with the following logic:

1. Page loads and checks if supporting backend precondition processes are complete
2. If supporting backend precondition processes are not complete then page displays a "Finalize Setup" button for user to click to trigger this
3. Clicking the "Finalize Setup" button will trigger the supporting backend precondition processes.
4. isFinalizing variable of true is set to state while backend processes are finalizing
5. isFinalizing state var of true should change "Finalize Setup" button to "Please Wait"

State variables and conditional rendering are included in the code below.  I implemented the sleep routine simply to mimic some work happening.  Currently the "Finalize Payment Cycle Setup" displays on initial page render, but text does not change to "Please Wait" after the button is clicked.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
  finalizePaymentCycleSetup(){
    this.setState({isFinalizing:true}, () => {
      //sleep for 3 seconds
      var e = new Date().getTime() + (3 * 1000);
      while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}      
    });
    this.setState({isFinalizing:false});
    this.setState({paymentCycleSetupIsFinalized: false});
  }

{ !paymentCycleSetupIsFinalized && (
          <div id="divFinalizeSetup">
            <input type="button"
              value={ this.state.isFinalizing ? "Finalizing Setup...Please Wait..." : "Finalize Payment Cycle Setup" }
              style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue', color:'white', position:"relative", left:-100}}
              onClick={() => { this.finalizePaymentCycleSetup() }}            
            ></input>
          </div> 
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `finalizePaymentCycleSetup` as below,you should use `setState` inside you api call

```
finalizePaymentCycleSetup(){

      this.setState({isFinalizing:true}, () => {
        //sleep for 3 seconds
     setTimeout(()=>{ this.setState({isFinalizing:false,paymentCycleSetupIsFinalized: false}); console.log('hgfd')},3000)   
      });

   }
```